# How to check variable type of cell content, distinguish between long and decimal

Tags: excel, validation, types, vba

I have sensus data that I need to pull together from a large number of workbooks.
As I don't intend to read all of them to check for possible wrongfully entered data I plan on highlighting cells that don't adhere to a determined datatype.

To do so I created a list that has the expected datatype for each row. For example they can be: `Long`, `String` or `Decimal`.

I know there exists this schema for detecting datatypes with a UDF, which is found all over the internet:

```
Public Function CellType(c)
    Application.Volatile
    Select Case True
        Case IsEmpty(c): CellType = "Blank"
        Case Application.IsText(c): CellType = "Text"
        Case Application.IsLogical(c): CellType = "Logical"
        Case Application.IsErr(c): CellType = "Error"
        Case IsDate(c): CellType = "Date"
        Case InStr(1, c.Text, ":") <> 0: CellType = "Time"
        Case InStr(1, c.Text, "%") <> 0: CellType = "Percentage"
        Case IsNumeric(c): CellType = "Value"
    End Select
End Function
```

However this doesn't distinguish between `Long` and `Decimal` datatypes. Is there a way to append that to this function, or is there another way that is better suited to distinguish these 3 datatypes: `String`, `Long` and `Decimal`.

Comment: varType not work?

Comment: Sounds like this could be handled with the [`CELL(type, [range])`](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/cell.php) formula!

Comment: @Rawrplus, Cell(type) returns: "Returns "b" if the cell is empty.
Returns "l" if the cell contains a text constant.
Returns "v" for all others. " according to the linked site. How does this distinguish between `Long` and `Decimal`?

Comment: @Qharr, thanks for the suggestion, going to look into that. First thing I noticed is that it works on defined variables, not on cell.value?

Comment: @Luuklag I'd noticed that as well. The same with `TypeName` I wonder if all numeric cell values are stored as `Double`. Another option would be you could try to detect the decimal separator. Something like `InStr(c.Value2, Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator))`

Comment: Sorry, perhaps should have worded myself better there. Unlucky naming coincidence, under `type` I meant the parameter, not the actual argument. 

You can use variations of the cell arguments, but I think the `Cell("format", Range)` would prove to be the most useful. You still would need to do some tinking in order for it to properly detect though, but it could get you on the right track.  Either way, now that I think about it, probably would be easier to simply loop through all the data, store it into temp variable and return the `.varType` as QHarr suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to test the numeric value:

```
Public Function CellType(c)
    Application.Volatile
    Select Case True
        Case IsEmpty(c): CellType = "Blank"
        Case Application.IsText(c): CellType = "Text"
        Case Application.IsLogical(c): CellType = "Logical"
        Case Application.IsErr(c): CellType = "Error"
        Case IsDate(c): CellType = "Date"
        Case InStr(1, c.Text, ":") <> 0: CellType = "Time"
        Case InStr(1, c.Text, "%") <> 0: CellType = "Percentage"
        Case IsNumeric(c)
            If c = Int(c) Then
                CellType = "Integer"
            Else
                CellType = "Decimal"
            End If
    End Select
End Function
```

**EDIT:**

Here's what is returned by this function, compared to some alternatives:

[image]

Used this function, to test `varType`:

```
Public Function CellVarType(c)
    Application.Volatile
    CellVarType = VarType(c.Value)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the addaption. I'll first explore the vartype route Qharr suggested, as that would simply be cleaner code, and more native functions.

Comment: Your use of the function name `CellType` leads me to think you're intending to use this function to determine the data type of a cell value. If that is the case, then `VarType` will not be able to distinguish between integer / decimal types - all cells containing numeric values will evaluate to `VarType 5 (vbDouble)`

Comment: I've edited my answer to show some comparative results.

Comment: If I go to the direct window of my VBA editor and type: `workcell = 123` followed by `Debug.Print(Vartype(workcell))` I get `2` as a result, being an integer. Doing the same with value `1.23` instead of `123` I indeed get `5` as a result. But for me that distinction is accurate enough. I wonder why your formula returns `5` for `123`

Comment: VBA variables and cell values are clearly treated differently. Put 123 in a cell, and select it. `foo = activecell.value: ?typename(foo)` returns Double. `foo=123: ?typename(foo)` returns Integer.

Comment: Finally got the time to implement this, and works like a charm.